# SMTP connection timeout in Sentry

Tags: django, sentry

I'm using Sentry to monitor a Django app. I copied the following (correct and tested) email settings from the Django app to my Sentry config file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@ookmijnbedrijf.nl'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Everything looks right on the SMTP Settings page, but when I try to send a test email I get this:

**Connection unexpectedly closed: timed out**

My Django app is sending emails correctly with these exact settings. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Sentry only supports SMTP with TLS (not SSL). Made an [issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/4252) about this.

Comment: I install sentry on my server and found that ssl is not supported.but my mail server only support ssl.not tls.